# Requested unknown parameter 'nRow' for row 0, column 0(DataTables)

Tags: ajax, datatables

i am using `DataTables with Ajax data`  i want to put `serial number` for datatable

i tried below code
html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table-striped table-bordered" id="salestbl">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>S.no</th><th>Invoice Number</th><th>Total Amount</th><th>Discoint Amount</th><th>Total Tax</th><th>Grand Total</th><th>Date</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>

    </table>
 </div>
```

ajax

```
 $('#salestbl').DataTable( {
                        "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
                            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
                           return nRow;
                        },
                         destroy: true,
                        data: response, 
                        columns: [   
                            { data: 'nRow' },
                             { data: 'invoiceNum' },     
                            { data: 'totalAmt' },    
                            { data: 'disAmt' },
                            { data: 'taxAmt' },
                            { data: 'grandTotal' },  
                            { data: 'date' }


                        ]
                    } );
```

when the dataTable targeted , it shows following `alert`

```
DataTables warning: table id=salestbl - Requested unknown parameter 'nRow' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

whats wrong in the above code please help me out.

Comment: The problem is likely to be with the format of your JSON response, which you haven't included here.  You've defined your data to use objects, so your response should look like the Ajax tab in this example: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: without row number everything is fine , if i add it gives that alert,i think its not the problem of json or something else problem with adding row number to dataTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer we need to declare `slno` in beans class and add it to the json String and send to ajax

```
$('#salestbl').DataTable( {
                        "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
                            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
                           return nRow;
                        },
                         destroy: true,
                        data: response, 
                        columns: [   
                            { data: 'nRow' },
                             { data: 'invoiceNum' },     
                            { data: 'totalAmt' },    
                            { data: 'disAmt' },
                            { data: 'taxAmt' },
                            { data: 'grandTotal' },  
                            { data: 'date' }


                        ]
                    } );
```

here it should not be   `{ data: 'nRow' },`  it should be the member variable of our class   `{ data: 'slno' },`

then data table will assign row number to the `first td of every row`
using

```
"fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
                                $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
                               return nRow;
                            },
```

above function , thank you to who ever replyed to my question.